# jQuery Plugin, keep reference to original element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-plugins

I am writing a jQuery plugin which creates a div element under the body element. I need to keep track of this element within that plugin instance.

```
$.fn.loadOverlay = function(command) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var container = $(this);

    if (typeof command != 'undefined' && command === 'destroy') {
      // remove the referenced DOM node
      return;
    }

    // somehow I need to keep a reference from the plugin instance to this created DOM node
    var overlay = $('<div>').css({
      width: container.outerWidth(true),
      height: container.height() + 1,
      top: container.position().top - 1,
      left: container.position().left
    }).addClass('overlay');

    // this is now globally appended without any reference to this plugin instance
    $('body').append(overlay);
  });
};
```

Usage would be something like

```
$('#someElement').loadOverlay(); // create the overlay
// ...
$('#someElement').loadOverlay('destroy'); // destroy the overlay
```

At first I just appended it underneath the selected element, but that caused trouble with tables.

One solution would be a counter inside the plugin itself which dynamically adds IDs or classes to the selected and created elements, but I don't know how to keep a variable static inside a jQuery plugin.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .selector and add it as class to overlay

```
$.fn.loadOverlay = function(command) {
    var selector = $(this).selector.replace("#",'').replace('.','').replace(/ /g,'');
```

Remove with selector

```
if (typeof command != 'undefined' && command === 'destroy') {
      $('.overlay.'+selector).remove() //here
      return;
}
```

and add selector as class to the overlay

```
var overlay = $('<div>').css({
      width: container.outerWidth(true),
      height: container.height() + 1,
      top: container.position().top - 1,
      left: container.position().left
    }).addClass('overlay ' + selector); //here
```

**Full code**

```
$.fn.loadOverlay = function(command) {
    var selector = $(this).selector.replace("#",'').replace('.','').replace(/ /g,'');
    alert(selector);
  return this.each(function() {
    var container = $(this);

    if (typeof command != 'undefined' && command === 'destroy') {
      $('.overlay.'+selector).remove()
      return;
    }
    // somehow I need to keep a reference from the plugin instance to this created DOM node
    var overlay = $('<div>').css({
      width: container.outerWidth(true),
      height: container.height() + 1,
      top: container.position().top - 1,
      left: container.position().left
    }).addClass('overlay ' + selector);
    // this is now globally appended without any reference to this plugin instance
    $('body').append(overlay);
  });
};
```

then

```
$('#someElement').loadOverlay();
$('#sameElement').loadOverlay('destroy'); //removes overlay connected to the selector element
```

Comment: The problem with this is that there may be also 'anonymous' elements without IDs.

Comment: Like $('div').loadOverlay() ?

Comment: This would be too general, but kind of yes. E.g.: `$('#results').find('tbody').loadOverlay()`. And this `tbody` has no ID.

Comment: using then $('#results').find('tbody') will add "resultstbody" as a class to the overlay
**Note** to destroy it you must use the same selector so $('#results').find('tody').loadOverlay('destroy');

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and time, but what if I had multiple of those? I guess I need unique names or something. But I don't know how to share an ID for example over multiple instances (within the plugin scope)

Comment: If you added overlay with the same selector and try to destroy it, i think it will remove all the overlays then, **EDIT** But you can use :last in the remove so it removes the most recent overlay with the same selector (overlay class name)

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/QRQpP/2/ click on add overlay multiple times then remove overlay it will remove the last overlay with that selector

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work in all cases. I need multiple overlays to many elements. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QRQpP/3/) to demonstrate. First add some overlays with first and second button. And then try to remove. Some constellations seem to break this construct.

Comment: @DanLee Thats because my onclick function was binded on button:first and button:last try this http://jsfiddle.net/QRQpP/5/

Comment: Alright I guessed there was a more low level solution but for now that'll do it. Thanks!